# How can I set up an environment variable to work with TCC?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, environment-variables, compile

I am trying to set up TCC on Windows 7, but I can't seem to make it work dynamically from cmd

```
To be able to invoke the compiler from everywhere on your computer by
just typing "tcc", please add the directory containing tcc.exe to your
system PATH.
```

So I changed my environment variable that said "Path" from:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

To:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\compilers\tcc\tcc.exe

But when I open cmd, it still says that "tcc" is not a recognized command.

Comment: Do you think `C:\compilers\tcc\tcc.exe` is a valid _folder_ name? Read [path](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the location to the .exe file named `tcc.exe` in your path. What you should do is add the location of the `folder` containing the `tcc.exe` file. So in your case the environmental path variable should be like this

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
>   C:\compilers\tcc

Assuming that your `tcc.exe` file is in the folder is `C:\compilters\tcc`

Answer (score 1):

`Path` command [(see windows command line reference)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490963.aspx):

> Sets the command path in the `PATH` environment variable, which is
>   *the set of **directories*** used to search for executable files. Used without parameters, path displays the current command path.

Your `C:\compilers\tcc\tcc.exe` is not a valid *folder* (directory) name;  supposedly, should be rather `C:\compilers\tcc\` or `C:\compilers\tcc` (with or without trailing `\` backslash).